# inter-rater agreement with more than 2 raters

Tags: python

I conducted an annotation process with 5 people, where they each analyzed 100 Tweets and classified each Tweet as being either positive (1) or negative (0). Which measure of inter-rater agreement is appropriate in this case? I know Cohen's Kappa only handles two raters, and I can't seem to find another appropriate measure.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming question as such, it may be more appropriate on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ but read the help: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help to check if the question would be suitable

Answer (score 2):

[Fleiss Kappa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fleiss%27_kappa) is a variant (kind-of) of Cohen Kappa fr multiple raters

Answer (score 0):

There are many coefficients available to calculate inter-rater reliability.

1. Fleiss' Kappa (Fleiss, 1971) - 'irr' package in R
2. Krippendorff's Alpha (Krippendorff, 1980) - 'irr' package in R
3. Conger's Generalized Kappa (Conger, 1980) - 'DescTools' package in R
4. Light's Kappa (Light, 1971) - 'irr' package in R
5. Iota (Janson & Olsson, 2001) - 'irr' package in R